# knockout bindinding handler using regular expression for phone number format

Tags: knockout.js

How to display phone number format using knockout bindinding handler using regular expression? phone number format like 
(xxx) xxx-xxxx.

My code is here

```
function formatPhone() {
    var regex = new RegExp('00(\d{2})(\d)(\d{3})(\d{2})');
    return regex;
}

ko.bindingHandlers.formatNumberText = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, formatPhone);
    }
};
```

and display phone number in .cshtml:

```
  <span data-bind="formatNumberText:Number"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that this way:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.formatNumberText = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var phone = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var formatPhone = function() {
            return phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
        }
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, formatPhone);
    }
};
```

Wrapping standard ko binding 'text'. 
The regexp used for phones represented with 10 digits string.
Check out fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nk22Z/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
this.phone = ko.observable(null).extend({ phoneUS: true });

<div class="col-sm-4" data-bind="validationElement: phone">
<input type="text" class="form-control height_25" data-bind="value: phone" />
</div>
```

phoneUS validation supports : (xxx) xxx-xxxx